# How to add CI tests on Github without exposing secrets?

Tags: python, github, continuous-integration, code-coverage

I have a (private) repo on Github, I want to

- display a badge showing code coverage for a project inside this repo
- track the evolution of this coverage
- keep my credentials hidden

In this repo, I have multiple projects, one of which is "my_big_project", which I want to track the code coverage.

```
 -- small_project
 -- my_big_project
    |-- main/
    |-- utils/
    |-- tests/
    |-- local.settings.json  # my secrets
```

I launch the tests with `coverage run -m unittest discover my_big_project/ "test_*.py"`

And my tests use secrets stored in `local.settings.json` (which is ignored with `.gitignore` to avoid being uploaded to Github).

How can I automate the execution of tests and track the coverage without uploading my secrets to Github's servers?

Comment: Thanks @YevhenKuzmovych, you can add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GitHub's Vault Secrets](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/vault-secrets) (which I understand, kinda contradicts the "without uploading my secrets to Github's servers" requirement, but it's either this or avoid using any secrets in the tests, e.x. mocking the APIs that require secrets)